# synchronize within a static method - Is this a class level lock?

Tags: java, java-threads

```
public static void getResult(HttpSession session) {
    synchronized(session) {
     ....
    }
}
```

Here synchronized block is on session, but the method is a static one. Does this result in a class level locking?

Comment: Just a little tip: it makes no sense for a getter with a void return type to exist.

Comment: did not put the whole logic here. actually returns a value, but did not share here.

Answer (score 2):

A thread will take a lock on the `session` object you have used in `synchronized(session)`. In your case it *does not matter if the method is static or not*, in both case lock, will be on the session object.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Is this a class level lock? The answer is hmm, no :)

Different threads here can sync on different objects as the lock is brought as parameter to the method.

A couple of examples:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    //Method is static
    public synchronized static void demoMethod(){

    }
}

or

public class DemoClass
{
    public void demoMethod()
    {
        //Acquire lock on .class reference
        synchronized (DemoClass.class)
        {
            //other thread safe code
        }
    }
}

or

public class DemoClass
{
    private final static Object lock = new Object();

    public void demoMethod()
    {
        //Lock object is static
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            //other thread safe code
        }
    }
}
```

Syncronisation brings overhead to your program. In a web application it is one of the responsabilities that the Application Container takes for you. Eventhough you could span own threads in a web app, it is discouraged.